# We don't need wood species tags do we?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm certain the answer is no but no harm in checking to be sure. In this question

[Will black walnut dull my carving tools](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2997/will-black-walnut-dull-my-carving-tools)

there was a tag for [walnut](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/walnut). I had removed it from the question in place of more appropriate tags. I think the general [wood](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wood) covers this area rather well.

Do we *really* need species specific tags? [oak](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oak), [white-oak](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/white-oak), [offwhite-oak](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offwhite-oak),[cherry](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cherry),[macadamia-nut](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macadamia-nut),[massaranduba](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/massaranduba),[venezualen-beaver-wood](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/venezualen-beaver-wood), [etc](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etc)

---

I would also suggest just removing [walnut](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/walnut)

Answer (score 5):

My uneducated opinion is no, these don't help. They could potentially help if the volume of questions on this site was so high that the organization was useful, but as it stand even for searchability with the volume of questions here searching for "walnut" is as effective as "[walnut]". Having the tags, while theoretically it might make sense, realistically it doesn't add much (although they don't seem to *hurt* so I'm not strongly anti either aside from my personal like of minimalism).

Plus a lot of the questions can be generally applied anyways.

For now maybe just [hardwood] and [softwood], maybe.